# Connect to mysql on vps

Tags: mysql, vps, pm2

I have a vps that is hosting a web page. I want to be able to query from mysql, which is also on the same vps. I have a server.js file, that I am running with pm2. However I just cannot get it to connect to my database.
server.js

```
 const express = require('express');
 const mysql = require('mysql');
 const cors = require('cors');

 const pool = mysql.createPool({
   host: 'my_vps_ip',
   user: 'admin',
   password: 'pass',
   database: 'userInfo'
 });

 const app = express();
 app.use(express.json());
 app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
 app.use(cors);
 app.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {
   const { username, password } = req.body;
   const query = `SELECT userId FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?`;
   pool.query(query, [username, password], (error, results) => {
     //if else
   });
 });

 const port = 3000;
 app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
 });
```

When I start this file with 'pm2 start server.js' on my vps, the pm2 logs give me

```
 0|server   |     at PoolConnection.connect 
 (/var/www/example.com/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
 0|server   |     at Pool.getConnection 
 (/var/www/example.com/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
 0|server   |     at Pool.query 
 (/var/www/example.com/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:202:8)
 0|server   |     at /var/www/example.com/server/server.js:24:8
 0|server   |     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 
 (/var/www/example.com/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
 0|server   |     at next 
 (/var/www/example.com/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
 0|server   |     at Route.dispatch 
 (/var/www/example.com/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
 0|server   |     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 
 (/var/www/example.com/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) {
 0|server   |   errno: -111,
 0|server   |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
 0|server   |   syscall: 'connect',
 0|server   |   address: '::1',
 0|server   |   port: 3306,
 0|server   |   fatal: true
 0|server   | }
```

I have opened port 3306 on my firewall with ufw.
I also have this as my /etc/mysql/my.cnf file

```
 !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
 !includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
 [mysqld]
 bind-address = my_vps_ip
```

I have also created an admin user and granted permission. This is what I get when I run
'SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;'

```
 +------------------+---------------------------+
 | User             | Host                      |
 +------------------+---------------------------+
 | admin            | %                         |
 | admin            | chart.example.com         |
 | admin            | localhost                 |
 | debian-sys-maint | localhost                 |
 | mysql.infoschema | localhost                 |
 | mysql.session    | localhost                 |
 | mysql.sys        | localhost                 |
 | root             | localhost                 |
 +------------------+---------------------------+
```

Can anyone help me understand how to connect to my db? I feel like I've tried everything I've been able to find and asked chatgpt but I just cannot get it to connect. The only way I've been able to connect to it is through mysql workbench. Thanks.